# What tests for a defective IC may be done with only a multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, testing

Linked to an earlier post [How do I test a circuit without an oscilloscope?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23434/how-do-i-test-a-circuit-without-an-oscilloscope)

**Background :**
Inching forward from the previous post I started to do a simple 555 astable with super super long duration  pulse (>30m). An LED was connected which should have flipped state at the end of the pulse.

The LED remained dark; so I connected the LED to the 12V (with the connector on the LED still linked to the rest of the circuit - thoughtless ; I know) to confirm the LED was not defective.

Now the LED glows continuously even after the pulse duration. So I started to think about how to test the 555 now, or any other IC in the future given the only instrument at my disposal is an analogue multimeter

**Question :**
What tests can be conducted on an IC to determine whether it is defective using only a multimeter? Is it even possible to test an IC standalone without a test-circuit?

Comment: It's not clear if mean just the 555 (in the realm of possible) or any IC.

Comment: @rawbrawb: Any (+: I'm sorry if that was not clear

Comment: Well, given that you probably don't know the precise functionality or implementation and the fact that some designs may include a 100 Million transistors ... I'll let you guess.  Some very simple IC's that you have the psuedo schematics for and which don't have many layers of transistors it starts to be possible.

Comment: Ugh ... i'm a moron. i never even thought of the improability of this question when applied to high density chips )+:

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not have fried the 555.

Start by changing out the timing capacitor so you will have about 0.5 sec ON, 0.5 sec OFF, and see if you see blinkenlight.

If that doesn't fix it, swap out the 555.

Now I'll give you the punchline.

You are almost certainly not going to be able to do what you want with a stock 555.  It has leakage currents that are too high compared to the very, very low charging and discharging currents you will have to use with your timing capacitor to achieve 30 minutes on, 30 minutes off.  Or even get anywhere near that.

You MIGHT be able to do it with a TLC7555 (I think: essentially a CMOS 555).  I kinda doubt it, though.

You will have a MUCH easier time with a baby PIC running a timing loop.  Or even a 555 driving a 4040 (I think) CMOS counter.